# Is it possible to return a value from a callback inside an async function without using Promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Very straightforward question, I know when I write an async function like this:

```
const res = (async () => 'hello')();
console.log(await res);
```

It should log: 'hello'

But, lets say I want to timeout the result inside my async function, I would have to create a new Promise so I can wrap the timeout callback in it, like this:

```
const res = (async () => 
   new Promise(resolve => 
     setTimeout(
       () => resolve('hello'), 1000
     )
   )
)();
console.log(await res);
```

Well, if async already returns a promise, why should I need to create a new Promise inside a function that is already a promise, to do something as simple as this?
Am I missing something or it is indeed designed to be this way?
Wouldn't it be better if I could just do something like this in a native way? Is it even possible?
For example:

```
const res = (async () => 
  setTimeout(
    () => resolve('hello'), 1000
  )
)();
console.log(await res);
```

Comment: You can't, because there is no `resolve()` function available in promise chain.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking `new Promise` is meant for legacy callbacks,.  And ideally you want to prevent using them as much as possible.

So in your example your using a `setTimeout`, and then resolving the string `hello`.   Instead of doing this, it would make more sense to create a delay function, that you could use again then just return `"hello"`

eg.

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function test() {

  const res = (async () =>  {
    await delay(1000);
    return "hello";
  })();
  
  console.log(await res);
  
}

test();
```

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately you need to convert a 'callback style' function into a promise, so you can't really get around making that promise. If you think this is a bit ugly, I would suggest using or building a utility function that does this for you.

Aside: unless you use `await` in a function, there's not really a good reason to mark it as async. This is better:

```
const res = new Promise(resolve => 
  setTimeout(
    () => resolve('hello'),
    1000
  )
);

console.log(await res);
```

I think a good way to think about async/await is that it makes certain promise-patterns easier to write, but not everything you can do with a plain promise can also be done with async/await. async/await makes a common pattern (MUCH) more legible.

Answer (score 1):

> Well, if async already returns a promise, why should I need to create a new Promise inside a function that is already a promise, to do something as simple as this?

An `async` function has three features:

- It creates a promise
- The promise resolves with the return value
- You can use `await` inside it

This makes it an excellent tool to *manage* other functions which return promises, as it lets you use `await` and write code that doesn't use lots and lots of callbacks.

It **doesn't** make it a universal tool for replacing all other uses of `Promise`.

You still need one for this.

---

> For example:
>
> ```
> const res = (async () => 
>   setTimeout(
>     () => resolve('hello'), 1000
>   )
> )();
> console.log(await res);
> ```

If this worked, then the `resolve` function would be springing out of nowhere, and the `return` value *wouldn't* be the value the function resolved as.

It would lose one of the benefits of `async` functions.

---

JavaScript is a big toolbox. Different tools are suited to different jobs.